# Set SQL command based on textBox text

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

I have the following gridView select command -

```
SelectCommand="SELECT [columnA] FROM [DB].[dbo].[TABLE] WHERE value = 1
```

When running it brings back the desired result into the gridview, however I am passing a string value from the previous page to populate a textBox and on page load want the gridview `SelectCommand` to be determined by that string.

So something like -

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

SelectCommand="SELECT [columnA] FROM [DB].[dbo].[TABLE] WHERE value = <%TextBox1.Text%>
```

However this is not picking up the string value on page load.

Comment: How are you passing the string from the previous page?

Comment: Please use SQL Parameters!

Comment: @AbZy the value is getting passed on the Request.QueryString["string"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of query is prone to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), You can use parameters instead. And Use the value you get from your QueryString.

```
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
comm.CommandText = "SELECT [columnA] FROM [DB].[dbo].[TABLE] WHERE value = @value";
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("value", Request.QueryString["string"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The comments above are true, this sort of methodology does expose you to SQL injection... but to answer your question:

This can be done in a number of fashions, although you no longer really need the text box as the value you require is being passed in using a Querystring. So give this a bash (VB.Net):

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender as Object, e as System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

  Dim myString As String = Request.Querystring("NameOfQuerystring")

  ' Call Sub and pass in value
  GenerateOutput(myString)

End Sub


Sub GenerateOutput(ByVal DBValue As String)

  'Perform Database call using the DBValue

  SelectCommand = "SELECT [columnA] FROM [DB].[dbo].[TABLE] WHERE value = " & DBValue

End Sub
```

If you would like to convert this to C#, use this link: [Convert VB.NET to C#](https://www.google.co.za/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/&ei=EMAHUaK9MenH0QXizoGwDg&usg=AFQjCNG3tnzIVnkd5WPUp-4OW0jwBFGclw&sig2=yKw5vubPr4cV7FvtDzV-xQ&bvm=bv.41524429,d.d2k&cad=rja)